# Mongodb exception, " MongoCursorException' with message '$ operator made object too large" What does it mean?

Tags: mongodb

```
MongoCursorException' with message '$ operator made object too large
```

I was trying to update some objects with an update command like

```
$collection->update({"_id" => array('$in' => array(2,3,4,5)) } ....)
```

and got this exception. Any hints about what it means ? So that I can proceed to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the source code, I believe it means that the update made the object larger than the document size allowed: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/db/update.cpp

Max document size was made 8Mb (from 4Mb) on 1.7.2: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1918

Then made 16Mb on 1.7.4: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-431

Comment: yes, this was exactly the case, this happened when I had done $pushAll beyond a certain limit on some objects. Another thing worth sharing is that $pushAll seems O(n) , it gets slow as object gets larger.