# Mongodb update with upsert fails

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Here is the statement which fails:

```
db.some_collection.update(query,modifier_set, upsert=True, safe=True)
```

**modifier_set** is of the form `{"$inc":{...}, "$addToSet":{...}}`

I get an `OperationFailure` error:

`$ operator made object too large`

Now, it's highly unlikely that my document it more that 16MB.

Any other possible reasons for such failure ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5679093

Comment: @hangy : But my object can't grow to 16 MB.

Comment: It's very likely you actually are increasing the size of the document to beyond the 16MB mark. Can you explain why you think it is unlikely?

Comment: @RemonvanVliet : We basically store the names of all the sites we have served in a month, all the IP addresses from where we got requests, number of requests from each country, and device used to access the site. Each document has a months data.
Is there a way to check the size of a document in mongodb ?

Comment: Not directly but you can copy the collection, remove all but one and check the size of the collection with db.col.stats(). Alternatively you can export 1 document and check the .bson file size

Comment: Small point on the usecase itself; it's sound like an extremely bad idea to have that sort of history in a single document. Why not just store them in a dedicated collection so you can actually query them and won't have to worry about growing document sizes?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's a bad scheme. I should re-implement this, in any case. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually a case of oversized document.
`db.collection_name.stats()` confirmed it.