# MongoDB, Python and PyMongo: Document size too large with BSONObj size is invalid

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am getting this error when writing to Mongo:

```
OperationalFailure caught
10334
{u'connectionId': 2365, u'code': 10334, u'ok': 1.0, u'err': u'BSONObj size: 17254820 (0xA4490701) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: 0:
```

This is a normal document full of strings and integers, constructed in Python, yet it's size seems to be 17,25MB. What would you do?

This is how the data looks like:

```
{ date: new Date(1417996800000), 
  visitors: [ { owner: "AS3320 Deutsche Telekom AG", ip: "82.148.15.23", views: 844 }, 
              { owner: "AS29314 VECTRA S.A.", ip: "173.235.42.25", views: 458 }, 
                ...
            ]
}
```

There are many, many elements in that array, yet I am surprised that the amount surpasses 16MB.

After limiting the size of the array down to 8500 elements, I am getting this PyMongo error:

```
$ operator made object too large
```

Comment: Can you normalize a little? Maybe 80% of the data is in 20% of the fields. Then you can move a couple of them to their own collection.

Comment: I updated my question to suit yours. It would be nice to have all page Impressions, yet it would conceivable to just cut the array when it exceed a certain length or size. Utilising GridFS seems to be to complicated?

Comment: Is there a way to determine the physical size of a list in python or the json object before writing to Mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of things to think about when designing your Mongo schemas, but generally the schema should reflect how you use your data. The [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) article series on the MongoDB Blog is a good start.

My first thought is to turn your documents "inside out" and store this kind of document in a collection:

```
{ date: new Date(1417996800000), owner: "AS3320 Deutsche Telekom AG", ip: "82.148.15.23", views: 844 },
{ date: new Date(1417996800000), owner: "AS29314 VECTRA S.A.", ip: "173.235.42.25", views: 458 },
...
```

This way you're not limiting how many unique users you can have per day. If you are indexing on the `date` field, looking up visitors by date is still efficient.

If you are not using the `owner` field much, maybe it can be moved to its own collection as well.

```
{ ip: "82.148.15.23", owner: "AS3320 Deutsche Telekom AG"},
{ ip: "173.235.42.25", owner: "AS29314 VECTRA S.A."},
...
```

Not a definitive answer, obviously, but it might be a start.

About checking the size of the document before writing (which I don't think is a good way to get around poor schema design). Data is handled as BSON by MongoDB internally so you can use the [`bson` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bson/0.3.3):

```
import bson
len(bson.dumps(my_document))
```

If you get the "operator made object too large" error, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224942/mongodb-update-with-upsert-fails).

Comment: Apreciate it. This is big data, so I went with a more flat schema.

Answer (score 0):

My document is oversized and I have a bad schema, obvisouly, also see: [Mongodb update with upsert fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224942/mongodb-update-with-upsert-fails)